# page loading infinitely when submit form

Tags: php, oracle

I'm using oracle db with php.When i'm trying to save data in two table from a single form.After click on submit my page loading infinitely .

```
    $acc_ins = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO ACC_MASTER(CODE, TITLE_CODE ,NAME , BS_GROUP_CODE ,  OP_BAL ,  OP_BAL_TAG ,PRINT_ON_CH, CR_LIMIT, 
                                ACTIVE_TAG ,REMARKS , INS_DATE, INS_UID)
                                VALUES($ACC_SEQ_CODE, '$ACC_TITLE_CODE', '$ACC_NAME', '$ACC_BS_GROUP_CODE', '$ACC_OP_BAL', 
                                $ACC_OP_BAL_TAG', '$ACC_PRINT_ON_CH', '$ACC_CR_LIMIT', '$ACC_ACTIVE_TAG', 
                                '$ACC_REMARKS' , '$ins_date', '$ins_uid')");

    $result = oci_execute($acc_ins).oci_execute(oci_parse('COMMIT'));

    $ACC_CODE = get_next_code('ACC_MASTER');
    $ACC_ADD_CODE                   =   "SEQ_ACC_ADDRESS_CODE_PK.NEXTVAL";
    $ACC_ADD_RANK                   =   get_next_rank("ACC_ADDRESS");
    $ACC_ADD_ADD1                   =   trim(strtoupper($_POST['ACC_ADD_ADD1']));
    $ACC_ADD_ADD2                   =   trim(strtoupper($_POST['ACC_ADD_ADD2']));
    $ACC_ADD_CITY_CODE              =   get_code_with_name('CITY_MASTER', 'NAME', $_POST['ACC_ADD_CITY']);
    $ACC_ADD_PIN_CODE               =   trim(strtoupper($_POST['ACC_ADD_PIN_CODE']));


    if((isset($_POST['ACC_ADD_ADD1']) && isset($_POST['ACC_ADD_ADD2']) && isset($_POST['ACC_ADD_CITY']) && isset($_POST['ACC_ADD_PIN_CODE'])))
    {
        $add_ins =  oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO ACC_ADDRESS(CODE, ACC_CODE, RANK, ADD1, ADD2, CITY_CODE, PIN_CODE, INS_DATE, INS_UID)
                                     VALUES($ACC_ADD_CODE , '$ACC_CODE', '$ACC_ADD_RANK', '$ACC_ADD_ADD1' , '$ACC_ADD_ADD2', 
                                    '$ACC_ADD_CITY_CODE', '$ACC_ADD_PIN_CODE' , '$ins_date', '$ins_uid') 
                                                                                                                ");
        $result2 = oci_execute($add_ins);
        if($result2){
            alert_success($actual_link);
        }else{  
            echo "data not saved <br>";
        }

    }
```

Comment: The provided code is not enough to understand and resolve your issue. For example, what's `alert_success()`.

Comment: its just a user defined functions for displaying a success message.